# SaveChanges to datebase when request has been approved

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a holiday tracking web app.

In my app employees can log on and request a holiday by creating holiday request form.

When they create a request form, it must be approved by a manager. So I don't want changes saved to the database until Approved has been set to true!

Do I do this by an if statement?

Do I have to create another page where managers can view all requests and set a specific one to true?

Here's my holiday request form model:

```
public partial class HolidayRequestForm
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
    public int HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated { get; set; }
    public int MonthCreated { get; set; }
    public int DayCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> YearOfHoliday { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Approved { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller part:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: HolidayRequestForms/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(holidayRequestForm);
    }
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            holidayRequestForm.Approved = true;
            db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(holidayRequestForm);
    }
```

But it does not work.

I would like my could to save changes to the database only after the request has been set to true.

Comment: Creating another page where manager can approve is advisable because there may be scenario where manager is not available to approve holiday request  and user is request for holiday. 
                                                                                              
 if you are not saving user holiday  request  that would be lost

Answer (score 0):

Do I do this by an if statement?

Yes, Once manager approves holiday store it in the table and check while submitting the form something like this:

```
If(holidayRequestForm.Approved)
{
//Write your logic of form submission.
}
```

Do I have to create another page where managers can view all requests and set a specific one to true?

This depends on your requirements and how your clients wants the page to look. A different page would be lot better to develop as approval and submission logics will be separated.

Comment: So would it be something like `if (holidayRequestForm.Approved = true) { 

                db.SaveChanges();

            }`

Comment: hmm, seems its not working the way I want it. since I removed `db.SaveChanges()` from the other if statement, it does add the request to the list of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid && (holidayRequestForm.Approved == true))
      {
         db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }

       return View(holidayRequestForm);
   }
```

Comment: get an error "operator && cannnot be applied to operands of type bool? and bool"

Comment: I added `ModelState.IsValid && holidayRequestForm.Approved = true` which fixed the error but now nothing happens. Doesn't even redirect. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now

Comment: Put breaker on `if condition` and check

Comment: It's no longer redirecting and no changes saved. Also holidayRequestForm.Approved = null with breakpoint

Comment: Yes because your `holidayRequestForm.Approved` property is `null` and it is not matching the `if condition`. Make sure the Approved value is set properly while sending it to `Create()` action.

Comment: I do have it set to default 0 or "false" in my sql server database but I guess that did'nt carry over when I used Ado.Entity data model. Will it work if it was defaulted to 0! I want the changes to apply when a manager sets it to approved just to be clear

Comment: Or I guess I could just format other if statments for when it's null and/or false!!